# Hide createBottomTabNavigator from children

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigationbar, react-native-navigation

I am building an app with Expo, and I want to have a Welcome screen when a user opens the app for the first time. I need the tab bar for the 'welcome' and 'auth' screens to be hidden once they have navigated past them to the 'map' screen.

With the updated createBottomTabNavigator from react-navigation, I am unable to have the bottom tab set visible to false with nested children.

Here is my App.js file:

```js
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { 
  createStackNavigator, 
  createBottomTabNavigator, 
  createAppContainer 
} from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider} from 'react-redux';

import store from './store';
import AuthScreen from './screens/AuthScreen';
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';
import MapScreen from './screens/MapScreen';
import DeckScreen from './screens/DeckScreen';
import ReviewScreen from './screens/ReviewScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = createAppContainer( 
      createBottomTabNavigator({
        welcome: {
          screen: WelcomeScreen,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
        },
        auth: {
          screen: AuthScreen,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
        },
        main: createBottomTabNavigator({
          map: MapScreen,
          deck: DeckScreen,
          review: createStackNavigator({
            review: ReviewScreen,
            settings: SettingsScreen
          })
        })
      })
    );

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [tabBarVisible](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbarvisible) to false using a function that is passed to `MapScreen` like this:

```
   constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
         isTabBarVisible: true,
      }
      this.hideTabBar = this.hideTabBar.bind(this);
   }

   hideTabBar() {
      this.setState({ isTabBarVisible: false })
   }

   ...
   render() {
   ...
      navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: this.state.isTabBarVisible }
      main: createBottomTabNavigator({
         map: <MapScreen hideTabBar={this.hideTabBar}/>,
         deck: DeckScreen,
         review: createStackNavigator({
           review: ReviewScreen,
           settings: SettingsScreen
         })
       })
   }
```

Then, in your `MapScreen` you can call:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.hideTabBar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I found another solution:

```js
 const MainNavigator = createAppContainer( 
      createBottomTabNavigator({
        welcome: {
          screen: WelcomeScreen,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
        },
        auth: {
          screen: AuthScreen,
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }
        },
        // Add navigationOptions to this screen
        main: {
          navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false },
          screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
            map: MapScreen,
            deck: DeckScreen,
            review: createStackNavigator({
              review: ReviewScreen,
              settings: SettingsScreen
            })
          })
        }
      })
    );
```

Comment: its working but it also adding Login Screen to TabBar